# What should be the right approach while developing android app when the prototype is ready

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development

I Have recently finished designing my mobile app in balsamic wireframe and now it's time build it in android studio.

What should be right approach for me?

should or can I create all the layout first before starting the hard coding.

or do one by one.

I would be a great if someone can help me with it.

thanks

I Haven't tried to implement the design in the android studio

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you please add more briefing about you problem or what you need?